# How can I add class to link inserted in TinyMCE?

Tags: class, hyperlink, insert, tinymce, addition

I would like to add class for every link to a file inserted in TinyMCE.

For example if I insert link to file.pdf file class should be exactly like file extension (class="pdf"). If link is not file I don't need any class.

Does someone do it already?

I know I must edit /link/plugin.js but at the moment I don't know exactly where should I check link value and add class to inserted link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND SOLUTION

```
else {
                            //get extension
                            var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
                            var ext = re.exec(href)[1];

                            editor.insertContent(dom.createHTML('a', {
                                class: ext,
                                href: href,
                                target: data.target ? data.target : null,
                                rel: data.rel ? data.rel : null
                            }, data.text));
                        }
```

It is part of /link/plugin.js - insertLink() function. Seems to work.